# is equivalence classes the same thing as cosets?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In abstract algebra (modern algebra), is the equivalence classes the same thing as cosets? 
In the lecture notes that I have, it seems as though they are but is it a universal rule for the equivalence classes to mean the same thing cosets?

or is the equivalence classes a subset of some set that equivalence relation holds ie (reflexivity, symmetric and transitivity)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset#Definition_using_equivalence_classes

Comment: You will have first to tell us what is **for you** "cosets", just like that...

Comment: # The Chaz 2.0, thanks for your answer, that is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 8):

As Hagen von Eitzen's answer shows, every *coset* is an equivalence class of a particular *equivalence relation*: if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, this induces an equivalence relation $\sim_H$ given by $a\sim_Hb\iff ab^{-1}\in H$ (note that since $H$ is a subgroup, $ab^{-1}\in H$ iff $ba^{-1}\in H$, so this is in fact symmetric).

In fact, more is true: in a precise sense, every "nice" equivalence relation on a group comes from a coset! Specifically, say that an equivalence relation $\sim$ on a group $G$ is a *congruence* if

- for all $a, b, c\in G$, $a\sim b\iff a^{-1}\sim b^{-1}$, and
- for all $a,b, c, d\in G$, if $a\sim b$ and $c\sim d$ then $ac\sim bd$.

That is, a congruence is an equivalence relation that *respects the group structure*. Then for a congruence $\sim$, let $H_\sim=\{g\in G: g\sim e\}$ be the $\sim$-class of the identity of $G$; it's not hard to show that $H_\sim$ is a subgroup, and the $\sim$-classes are exactly the $H_\sim$-cosets.

That said, there are lots of "bad" equivalence relations on a group. For instance, on the group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation given by $$m\sim n\iff m=n=17\mbox{ or }m\not=17\not=n;$$ this divides the group into two classes, $\{17\}$ and $\{$everything but $17\}$. This equivalence relation of course does not come from a coset, but is an equivalence relation nonetheless.

OK, that's a stupid example. But there are even *interesting* equivalence relations on groups that aren't congruences, so don't divide the group into cosets of some fixed subgroup. For example, consider the relation $g\sim h$ if there is some [*group automorphism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_isomorphism#Automorphisms) $\alpha$ of the group with $\alpha(g)=h$. This is an equivalence relation on $G$ (automorphisms are invertible and composable) whose classes are called *orbits*; it's studied seriously (I've actually seen it most in mathematical logic!) but in general is not a congruence.

That said, based on personal experience I'll (tentatively) say that **most interesting equivalence relations on groups are congruences**.

Answer (score 4):

They are related.

For example if $G$ is a group and $H$ a subgroup, then **cosets** are subsets of $G$ that are of the form $aH$ with $a\in G$. 
By the group properties of $H$, we can infer that cosets are either disjoint or identical. Also, they are all non-empty and their union is all of $G$. That makes the set of cosets a **partition** of $G$. And a partition is "the same" a an **equivalence relation,** a la $x\sim y$ iff $x$ and $y$ are in the same part of the partition (and the parts of the partition are then jsut the equivalence classes of the equivalence relation $\sim$).

But of course we could define totally different equivalence relations (or partitions) on $G$ where the equivalence classes are not cosets.